# How to create a div with black background to fit right behind a div?

Tags: html, css

I have an image, on hover i will animate it to fade out to opacity: 0.4;, the fading out is fading to white, but i liked to fade to black, so i found a solution is to change the background color of the body to black. Then my fadeout will be towards black. So the plan i'm trying to do is create a div with black background to have the same width and height as my img but i don't know how to do it.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="img_section ">            
            <img class="eight columns test_img" src="images/wpdevshed-portfolio.jpg" alt="logo">
            <h2 class="caption">Jack<br />Portfolio1</h2>
        </div>
</div>
```

The width and height of my image is 500 by 500. So basically i want a black bg to be behind this image, so when i fadeout it will be towards black.. Anyone know of any simple ways that i can achieve it instead of using body{background-color:black};?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle of what you have done so far?

Comment: Does this go some way to solving the problem? http://codepen.io/notionparallax/pen/AKtak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acheive this by giving background to parent div. Below is the simple code that helps you.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/ar387hav/

CSS:

```
.container {
  background: #000;
  position:relative;
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.container img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.container img:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: i'm using left-right margin:10px, is there a way that i can prevent my margin from getting filled up with the bg color as well?